# Install mysql before xampp on windows 7

Tags: mysql, xampp

Should I install mysql before installing xampp on windows 7, or does xampp comes with mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xampp server comes with mysql. xampp stands for x(cross platform), apache, mysql, php, perl

Answer (score 1):

Xampp already comes with MySQL

Install Xampp, open it, then '`Start`' Apache and MySQL

Go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` to check if it is working fine